# Graphics and windows programming in C++

Tags: c++

Friends I read that many windows applications like Firefox browser are written in C++. So I decided to learn C++and learnt many concepts of object oriented programming. But all I can do now is simply make console program that runs in a command prompt screen with white text in black background. How can I create graphics and gui for my software. Also I see in installation directory that program fines has many different files. How can I work with many files and create a real life windows software (hey I'm not asking you how to code Microsoft office or so... Just some simple application)
Could you give me an idea how a program like Google chrome is made

Comment: You'll need a framework to create the gui (like WinForms) or graphics (like direct3D). You maybe want to try [Visual Studio 2015 Comunity](https://www.visualstudio.com/de-de/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx) (Remember to add c++ at the installation)

Comment: Or try Qt. Not only is it better than the MS APIs, but also works on most other platforms.

Comment: Use Qt Creator, look here http://qt.io

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a framework, because you need to communicate with the operating system. This also means your application will be platform dependent.

IMHO the best start is to skip learning (the ugly) Windows API and learn some multiplatform framework like Qt.

With Qt the start is easy. Just download Qt with Qt Creator, click "Wellcome/Examples", select any example, compile and you're just running your first graphic app!

The list of examples can be also found here http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtexamplesandtutorials.html which should give you an idea what you can do.

Comment: Of course I am done with C++. Inheritance polymorphism pointers overloading functions and all that stuff

Comment: Ok. (In my last deleted note) I wanted to say that GUI programs are usually big. This means you need to structure your code very carefully and use for example design patterns or signal/slot mechanism... In console app I use STL, but with Qt I use Qt library. That's why the GUI programming is different.

Comment: +1 for "the ugly". Definitivley you are right, WinAPI can be a real pain in the head. I also suggest starting with a framework. Either Qt or Gtkmm.

Comment: @Sahil: "Of course I am done with C++." - LOL - I've been coding for ~35 years, about half of which has been with C++, and I don't consider myself anywhere near "done with C++" yet. Of course if you've already mastered template metaprogramming, STL, boost and all the new stuff in C++11, C++14, etc, then I take my hat off to you!

Comment: Paul.. By saying I am done with C++ I didn't mean I am a master of it.... But what I was trying to say that I have enough knowledge In C++ so that I can move on to learn graphics programming.... I really respect your knowledge and experience

Comment: @Sahil: no problem, and no offence intended, but I think you may still be in for a bit of a culture shock when you start looking at "real world" C++ programs. Good luck, anyway!